# Check if movement ended

Tags: phaser-framework

When I start a `matter.sprite` movement in Phaser 3 with `sprite.setVelocity(vx, vy)`, how can I easily check if the movement ended?

The problem is that `sprite.body.velocity.x == 0` seems to be only true in the case when the sprite bounces off of an obstacle, and momentarily stops. But I need to know when the whole movement actually ended.

Comment: Do you control the sprite movement or is it a sort of a npc

Comment: @nazimboudeffa both :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this was a problem on my side. I was testing a maximum velocity of all objects to check if there is a movement on the scene. But I was doing it like this:
        `maxVelocity.x = Math.max(maxVelocity.x, child.body.velocity.x);`
Which doesn't work well with *negative values*. `Math.abs(...)` was needed :)

Comment: no problem at all, so, next time, don't ask, JUST ASK ;) in fact it's very good to have Q&A in the community's stackoverflow because it's well referenced on search engines